# Asp.net Core IAuthorizationFilter :Top level attribute returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using .NET core 3 and for AuthorizationFilter inherited IAuthorizationFilter.
On my top level attribute I have added custom attribute(ModulePermission).

I need to get the value of the attribute on  AuthorizeActionFilter -> OnAuthorization function.

However, I can access current action customattribute(ActionPermission). But my top level attribute is null.

```
(
var module = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<ModulePermissionAttribute>(true).FirstOrDefault(i => i is ModulePermissionAttribute); 
)
```

Example

Api Controller:

```
[ModulePermission(Module.Product)]
[Route("api/products")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductController : BaseApiController
{
     public ProductController()
     {
     }

    [Route(""), HttpPost, ActionPermission(Action.READ)]
    public Response<Product> Get()
    {
            // some code
     }
}
```

Authorization Class:

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters; 
  
    public enum Module
    {
        User,
        Product
    }
    
    public enum Action
    {
        Read,
        Delete,
        Add,
        Edit
    }
    
     [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
     public class ActionPermissionAttribute : Attribute
     {
        private Action _action;
        public Action action { get { return action; } }
    
        public ActionPermissionAttribute(Action action = Action.Read)
        {
           _action = action;
        }
      }
    
     [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
     public class ModulePermissionAttribute : Attribute
     {
         private string _module;
         public string Module { get { return _module; } }
         public ModulePermissionAttribute(string module = "")
         {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(module))
            {
                 _module = "Novalue";
            }
            else
            {
                 _module = module;
             }
          }
         public ModulePermissionAttribute(Type module)
         {
                _module = module.Name;
            }
        }
    
    
        public class AuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
        {
            public AuthorizeAttribute()
            : base(typeof(AuthorizeActionFilter))
            {
            }
        }
    
        public class AuthorizeActionFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
        {
            public AuthorizeActionFilter()
            {
            }
            public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
            {
                bool isAuthorized = //check authorized or not
                var actionDescriptor = (context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor);
    
                var module = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<ModulePermissionAttribute>(true).FirstOrDefault(i => i is ModulePermissionAttribute); 
               // **here module is always null**

                var method = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<ActionPermissionAttribute>(false).FirstOrDefault(i => i is ActionPermissionAttribute);
    
                // check module and method exists for the user
    
                if (!isAuthorized)
                {
                    context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer
By Using EndpointMetadata

```
var module = context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<ModulePermissionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope this helps someone